# A Conversion between Formats

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem joining two tables on columns of various types (the Error converting data type `varchar` to `numeric` message appears).
The joining logic has to be like that:

```
ON LC_YEAR (decimal(4,0), null)=DATE (datetime, null)
```

Tried various conversions, but failed. Any ideas on how the conversion should look like?
Immensely thankful,
Y.

Comment: Why would you be comparing year to a datetime anyway? That makes no sense. Should you be extracting the year part of the date? And is your message indicating that `DATE` is actually a `varchar` which doesn't contain a value which can be converted into a date?

Comment: I have no idea of what `LC_YEAR()` is but I suspect you aren't asking the right question at all—conversion between formats is a very thick subject. Do you by chance just want to determine whether a date belongs to a given year?

Answer (score 0):

LC_YEAR is just a column containing years (four digits), and date has this format: mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss:mmm. All I have to do is to join the tables on these two columns - perhaps, by, indeed, extracting the year out of the DATE column (but year(DATE) function doesn't work either). Indeed, there is a contradiction between the message and the column formats, but I saw what the format was in the table properties. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Resolution to this rests in knowing for certain what the actual data type is of each field.

You have indicated LC_YEAR is decimal and `DATE` is datetime;

But you have also indicated the "format" of `DATE` is mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss:mmm if the data type is datetime then the format is irrelevant, if that field is varchar then format is relevant. So the information available is a bit confusing. Here are some ideas for the conversion.

```
`LC_YEAR`   `DATE`  
data Type   data type   
decimal     datetime    LC_YEAR = YEAR(`DATE`)
varchar     datetime    LC_YEAR = CAST(YEAR(`DATE`) AS VARCHAR)
varchar     varchar     LC_YEAR = CAST(YEAR(str_to_time(`DATE`,'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss:mmm')) AS VARCHAR)
decimal     varchar     LC_YEAR = YEAR(str_to_time(`DATE`,'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss:mmm'))
```

---

Ideally you would not need to join involving data type conversions